# What are the available options to emulate devices using driver.emulateDevice()

Tags: karate, client-hints

I'd like to use Chrome to emulate different devices to run my frontend tests on different emulators. in the documentation, I found the following example

`And driver.emulateDevice(375, 812, 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1')`

where can I get a list of different options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is completely up to you, Karate just takes the string you provide and uses it "as is".

For further research into what that string is all about, you can refer this: https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/

Comment: Thanks.ill check it out